# How can I override a Magento controller?

Tags: php, magento, overriding, controllers

I need to check the validity of a coupon code on the checkout/cart page with server-side code.

Magento already ships with a similar check in place. However, I need to add one to see if a user is connected or not: what would be the best way to extend/override that action in Magento?

I know I can copy the controller PHP file to the `/app/code/local/` folder tree, but I'm wondering whether there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Anything besides modifying the `core` is good in my opinion.  With that said create a simple module with a controllers directory and etc with config.xml:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                         <My_Module before="Mage_Checkout">My_Module_Checkout</My_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

See here for more details on how to extend the frontend controller:
http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/

Comment: Thnak you, in fact I did that, but I need to explicitly add a require on the require_once("Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php");

Comment: Can you update your post with the full config.xml and controller code?