# How to create custom customer field in Magento login page?

Tags: magento, authentication

I was searching for the latest method to add custom fields on Magento 1.6 login page. All the articles that I found was for earlier versions on Magento and It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit `customer/form/login.phtml` template
2. Edit `loginPostAction` from `Mage_Customer_AccountController` (see [How can I override a Magento controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6374344/379792))