# Magento overriding core controller in local folder

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have copied **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php** and overrided one function. I have also refreshed caches, but overrided controller is not called, instead original controller is called.

Why isn't my override working? I have done same kind of override for other core files and that worked well.

Comment: Controller files are not (cannot be) included by the autoloader, hence the include path precedence does not apply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Is compilation turned off?
2. Try creating your own controller to overriding a core controller instead of copying and editing a Magento core file.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller

See also: [How can I override a Magento controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374344/how-can-i-override-a-magento-controller)

Comment: 1. Compilation is turned off. 2. I created own controller, but it ruined something else, so I figured out that it would be easier to just override it like that.

Comment: Is your OnepageController already overridden/extended by some other module?

Comment: No it's not, I checked this form Eclipse and even added debug to original file and original file with debug was called.

Comment: I managed to override controller with changes to my own module config.xml, I had to use line <my_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">My_Module</my_Module>. Apparently you cannot override files in controllers folder.